# Angular Typescript Type 'FormData' is missing the following properties from type

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an interface

```
export interface IDetails {
  action: string;
  roleId: number;
  anotherId: number;
  userDetails: IUserIds[];
  payload: FormData
}

export interface IUserIds {
  userId: string;
  comments?: string;
}
```

and In typescript file I use this interface to create some payload

```
const reqPayload: IDetails = {
          action: type,
          roleId: this.roleId,
          anotherId: this.anotherId,
          userDetails: this.userDetailsArray
        }

 const payload = new FormData();
 const blobData = new Blob([JSON.stringify(reqPayload)], { type: 'application/json' });
 payload.append('approverWorkflowReq', blobData);

 this.sharedService.postDetails(payload).subscribe(res => {});
```

I just get an error `Type 'FormData' is missing the following properties from type 'IDetails': action, roleId, anotherID, userDetails, payload`

I've added FormData in interface. I'm not sure What does this error mean how do i resolve it

Comment: Which line is the error being reported on?

Answer (score 0):

We can make `payload` property as optional (`payload?: FormData;`) to get rid of the TypeScript error.

In the original code, it's mandatory and as you have not supplied a value for `payload` you are getting this TypeScript error:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import 'zone.js';

export interface IDetails {
  action: string;
  roleId: number;
  anotherId: number;
  userDetails: IUserIds[];
  payload?: FormData; // <- changed here!
}

export interface IUserIds {
  userId: string;
  comments?: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{ name }}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.dev/overview">
      Learn more about Angular
    </a>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  roleId = 1;
  anotherId = 2;
  userDetailsArray = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    const type = 'test';
    const reqPayload: IDetails = {
      action: type,
      roleId: this.roleId,
      anotherId: this.anotherId,
      userDetails: this.userDetailsArray,
    };

    const payload = new FormData();
    const blobData = new Blob([JSON.stringify(reqPayload)], {
      type: 'application/json',
    });
    payload.append('approverWorkflowReq', blobData);
    reqPayload.payload = payload;

    this.postDetails(reqPayload).subscribe((res) => {});
  }

  postDetails(payload: IDetails) {
    return of(true);
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-snbrgp?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&template=node&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: The above solution didn't work for me. I'm simply passing `FormData` as the payload, hence we don't need the interface `IDetails` map to the payload i'm passing to http request.

Comment: @Urvashi Form data is meant for images, its confusing why you want to store that data inside a blob, so try the modified answer! where I set the payload on the request object and send that instead of the FormData itself! if this still does not help, try setting the type of payload arguement of the method `postDetails` to `FormData` and check if that solves your error!